# realloc returns null

Tags: c, realloc

I write the following files to solve question https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2442487/dashboard#s=p0

In the solution, I use a stack (my first stack implementation in c), however when it dynamically reduce stack size from 64 to 32, the program crashed.

After some debugging, I found that NULL is returned when realloc is called to adjust the buffer size. But I have no idea what is wrong or even how to figure out what is wrong.

Please help OTZ.

Stack.h:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#define DECL_STACK_TYPE(type, name) \
typedef struct stack_##name { \
    type * buffer; \
    int size; \
    int top; \
} * name; \
void stack_delete(name s) { \
    free(s->buffer); \
    free(s); \
} \
type stack_peek(name s) { \
    return (s->buffer[s->top]); \
} \
int stack_isEmpty(name s) { \
    return (s->top == -1); \
} \
int stack_isFull(name s) { \
    return (s->top == s->size-1); \
} \
name newStack(int size) { \
    if (size<4) size = 4; \
    name s; \
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack_##name)); \
    s->buffer = (type*) malloc(size*sizeof(type)); \
    s->size = size; \
    s->top = -1; \
    return s; \
} \
int stack_push(name s, type item) { \
    type * temp; \
    if (stack_isFull(s)) { \
        temp = (type*) realloc(s->buffer, s->size*2*sizeof(type)); \
        if (!temp) return 0; \
        s->size *= 2; \
    } \
    s->buffer[++s->top] = item;\
    return 1; \
} \
type stack_pop(name s) { \
    type temp; \
    temp = s->buffer[s->top--]; \
    if (s->top * 4 <= s->size && s->size >= 8) { \
        s->size /= 2; \
        type * temp_buffer = s->buffer; \
        s->buffer = (type*) realloc(s->buffer, s->size*sizeof(type)); \
    } \
    return temp; \
}
```

A.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"Stack.h"    

typedef struct {
    int origin;
    int end;
    int count;
} J,*pJ;    

int compare_J(const void * ip1, const void * ip2) {
    pJ p1 = (pJ) ip1;
    pJ p2 = (pJ) ip2;
    if (p1->origin != p2->origin) {
        return (int) (p1->origin-p2->origin);
    } else if (p1->end != p2->end) {
        return (int) p1->end-p2->end;
    } else {
        return (int) p1->count-p2->count;
    }
}    

DECL_STACK_TYPE(J, stack)       

int ticket_cost(int from, int to, int n) {
    int i,ans;
    ans = 0;
    for (i=0;i<to-from;i++) {
        ans += n-i;
    }
    return ans;
}    

int main() {
    freopen("A.in","r",stdin);
    //freopen("A.out","w",stdout);    

    int T,N,M;
    J j[1000],j_temp;
    int i,k,t,ans,index,cur_end,cur_count,iter;

    scanf("%d",&T);
    for (t=1;t<=T;t++) {
        ans = 0;
        scanf("%d %d",&N,&M);
        for (i=0;i<M;i++) {
            scanf("%d %d %d",&(j[i].origin),&(j[i].end),&(j[i].count));
            ans += ticket_cost(j[i].origin, j[i].end, N)*(j[i].count);
        }
        qsort(j,M,sizeof(J),compare_J);
        stack s = newStack(4);
        index = 1;
        stack_push(s,j[0]);
        for (i=0;i<M;i++) {         
            cur_end = j[i].end;
            cur_count = j[i].count;
            while (index<M && j[index].origin<=cur_end) {
                stack_push(s,j[index++]);
            }
            while (cur_count > 0) {
                j_temp = stack_pop(s);
                k = (cur_count<j_temp.count)?cur_count:j_temp.count;
                ans -= ticket_cost(j_temp.origin, cur_end, N)*k;
                cur_count -= k;
                if (j_temp.count > k) {
                    j_temp.count -= k;
                    stack_push(s,j_temp);
                }
            }
        }
        stack_delete(s);
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n",t,ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 thank you so much!!! Such a life saver!

Comment: What's up with all those backslashes? Functions aren't macros, even if they (weirdly) live in a header ...

Comment: @unwind I wrote it as macros for future reuse for programming contests. And it is my first time to write macro, so I wanted to practise. header file also for my reuse purpose (I don't know if it is weird.)

Comment: Ah, I failed to see the initial `#define`. That's ... really strange. :)

Comment: @LevinKwong If you're trying to write the macro so that you could simultaneously have several type-specialized implementation of the same data structure, you should probably prefix the functions with the type name and (at the very least) declare them static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is a reasonable value for `realloc` to return

`realloc` will return:

- the same location, if it was not moved, but the new size was accommodated
- a new block if the data was moved to allow for the new size
- NULL if it failed to allocate storage for the new size, and thus the block pointed by ptr was not modified.

In short, you ran out of memory

Comment: Or his `s->size` was 0, realloc may return NULL if you try to allocate 0 bytes